# the page refreshing issue on submit form, using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement submit this form using jquery in this way

> `<%= link_to('ОКЕЙ', 'javascript:;', id: "create_todo_form")%>`

data is transferred to the table, but the page is not updated, to display the changes, so I'm trying to add a line `location.reload();` to this code

application.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#todo_form").hide("slow");
    });

    $("#create_todo_form").click(function(){
        $("#form_id").submit();
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

And after this change the page is updated, however, submit is not implemented. 
The form is in this file
index.html.erb

```
<div id="todo_form">

    <%= form_with model: @todo, id: :form_id do |form| %>
    <p>
        <% form.label :text %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :text, placeholder: "Название задачи" %>
    </p>

        <%= form.select( :project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id, :title)) %>

    <p>
        <%= link_to('ОТМЕНА', 'javascript:;', id: "hide")%>
        <%= link_to('ОКЕЙ', 'javascript:;', id: "create_todo_form")%>

    </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

How could I fix this so that the data is added and the page is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect using your controller.

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  def example
    # Your Code here
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back}  #you may use a definite path like root_path instead of :back
    end
  end

end
```

Remove `location.reload()` after these changes.